# Ubuntu 15.04 SLOW BOOT

Tags: boot, 15.04

I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 from 14.10 two days back. The boot time has increased a lot since then. I installed the boot-up manager(bum) and deselected Bluetooth and scanner support options. The boot time is still the same. Its actually taking more than a minute. What should I do?

Comment: Try `bootchart` on both 14.10 and 15.04 - it may help on why things are taking so long. Don't be surprised if this question is marked "off-topic" for not being reproducible.

Comment: If yo run 'dmsg > Desktop/file.txt' you'll get a file on your desktop with the timed info for the last boot. Then you can tell us which process was the culprit or which entry took longer. And we'll se what can be done.

Comment: You can also look for culprits running "systemd-analyze blame". Or if there's any long-duration gaps in the "dmesg" output, the log entries that follow might give clues.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/615006/ for just one example of how using the diagnostic tools that come with systemd give far more information in a question.

Comment: did you ever fix this? for me, bootchart doesn't produce any output. But I did find useful information in the `sudo journalctl` output - for me it seems to have been an outdated cryptswap entry, which caused the boot to wait until timeout (90 seconds)

Comment: @codeling: bootchart should generate a bootchart.png which documents the boot-process

Comment: @codeling I really recommend to take a look at `dmesg`; for me it showed that the driver for my WLAN-stick took like 20 seconds (you can see the the time elapsed since the start of the boot process in microseconds...)