# Why does systemd boot so much slower than upstart

Tags: boot, systemd

Recently upgraded from 14.04 to 15.04 and immediately noticed my boot times went from 10-20 seconds all the way up to 120 seconds.

Can confirm that systemd is at least part of the problem, because if I manually select to boot using upstart (from the GRUB menu), the machine boots in 10-20 seconds.

Here is my systemd-analyze blame output: http://pastebin.com/iE3nrwRS

Here is my systemd-analyze critical-chain output: http://snag.gy/dX9q3.jpg

I will be happy to provide more information as requested.

**Edit 1**

I know this doesn't answer the question, but I think I am just going to permanently move back to upstart (something that works): https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers#Permanent_switch_back_to_upstart

Comment: This isn't really a GRUB question.  It isn't even an upstart question.  It's by all appearances a NetworkManager question.  And those analyses are quite similar to this already asked question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/615006/

Comment: I realise it's not a GRUB related question, I just mentioned that proof that using systemd (as opposed to upstart) is the cause. I noticed that question you mentioned before posting this and was hesitant to try out the proposed solution because of the mentioned side effects. Why should I have to do that anyway if upstart does not require me to?

Comment: I was trying to make the point that systemd  has taken (me at least) a step backwards, instead of forwards and I think that it's ridiculous that I should have to deal with it via potentially hazardous configuration workarounds.

Comment: If you realized that it wasn't a GRUB question, then _why did you tag it as one_?

Comment: I didn't realise tags had to relate so strongly to the question. I thought they were just to attract people to the question.

Comment: Post the test.svg you got from `systemd-analyze plot > test.svg` on a pastebin

Comment: @freshquiz - if you were asking about iptc_commit() in #ubuntu IRC today, the source is under TC_COMMIT() in libiptc.c in the bz2 archive you downloaded from the LFS link I gave you. If this is not you, please ignore this :)

Comment: @markdwhite haha nice find, thank you. I managed to find it after speaking with the guys on #linux.

Comment: @freshquiz - cool, glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Boot time was approx. 100s. Also tried "systemd-analyze blame" and "systemd-analyze critical-chain", but that didn't really help. Switching to upstart dramatically decreased boot time.

Finally, I found out that the swap configured in /etc/fstab was invalid. The configured swap partition didn't exist any more. After I deleted the entry in /etc/fstab, the boot time with systemd went back to normal.

So, I recommend you to check all entries in /etc/fstab if they are valid.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but doesn't help my issue. I can see the results of my /etc/fstab configuration in "/var/log/kern.log" and there are no errors.