# Systemd boot on 15.04 is extremely slow compared to Upstart

Tags: boot, 15.04, 14.10, upstart, systemd

After upgrading from Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04, my boot time increased dramatically from around 30s to more than ten minutes. The screen stays black for quite a long time, but when waiting long enough I reach the logon screen. When I manually switch back to Upstart booting is as fast as before.

What puzzles me is that the logs consistantly still show boot times around 30 seconds although in reality I wait for ages until I can logon.

Also an invalid swap partition in `/etc/fstab` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618386/why-does-systemd-boot-so-much-slower-than-upstart) was not the culprit.

Here is my dmesg output of my last systemd boot http://pastebin.com/KTyVHkkn , but as mentioned, the boot time is in fact much longer.

Same for `systemd-analyze critical-chain`:

```
graphical.target @35.170s
└─multi-user.target @35.170s
  └─smbd.service @34.874s +295ms
    └─nmbd.service @32.025s +2.847s
      └─network-online.target @32.022s
        └─network.target @26.271s
          └─wpa_supplicant.service @26.842s +60ms
            └─basic.target @24.166s
              └─sockets.target @24.165s
                └─dbus.socket @24.165s
                  └─sysinit.target @24.160s
                    └─networking.service @24.016s +143ms
                     └─apparmor.service @23.657s +357ms
                       └─local-fs.target @23.652s
                         └─shared.mount @23.538s +112ms
                           └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-fbff68ef\x2d6da1\x2d432a\x2d8500\x2d60795a470afd.service @16.688s +6.743s
                              └─local-fs-pre.target @16.627s
                                └─systemd-remount-fs.service @16.546s +57ms
                                  └─systemd-fsck-root.service @15.972s +573ms
                                    └─system.slice @3.508s
                                      └─-.slice @3.507s
```

Any hints and feedback is very much appreciated.

Comment: I read this, but it just tells me to permanently switch back to Upstart as a workaround, but I'd like to fix it for systemd.