# Slow Boot Time on Ubuntu 17.10.1 (systemd-analyze blame results)

Tags: boot, shutdown, performance

I'm very new to Ubuntu.

My PC has had very slow boot and shut down times (for 2 days), I reduced the shut down time with this tutorial (https://sites.google.com/site/installationubuntu/home/ubuntu-16-4-lts/make-slow-shutdown-faster) but PC still has some latency problem.

Using `systemd-analyze blame` from the terminal shows:

```
17.990s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 7.379s dev-sda1.device
 5.271s dev-loop0.device
 5.268s dev-loop1.device
 5.264s dev-loop2.device
 4.067s snapd.service
 2.015s postfix@-.service
 1.909s plymouth-quit-wait.service
 1.467s udisks2.service
 1.291s fwupd.service
 1.248s networking.service
  536ms accounts-daemon.service
  447ms tlp.service
  433ms ModemManager.service
  407ms NetworkManager.service
  357ms lm-sensors.service
  349ms keyboard-setup.service
  339ms preload.service
  339ms apparmor.service
  333ms grub-common.service
  333ms mono-xsp4.service
  312ms systemd-logind.service
  304ms apport.service
```

I think there is a problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/615006/ubuntu-15-04-network-manager-causing-slow-boot on  `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` taking a lot of time.

Comment: You do not have any problems. Problems starts with 2-5 minutes bootup. This may occur with many local and network mounts and many servers/daemons. There is no reason to tune system boot-time. It boots once and then you do your work. Do not touch anything systemd-related if it works. If you are newbie, the results of such tuning may result in re-installation.

Comment: @Rinzwind , I read the article and apply some of them, they did work but the actual launch time didn't change.

Comment: @N0rbert , I understand, I removed the 3rd party apps in list, new results are very good but launch time didn't changed.  (http://oi67.tinypic.com/mhcdcm.jpg)

Comment: **Note to Close Voters:** I don't think this is opinion based because hundreds of other questions about slow boot times are on-topic here.

Comment: Is this question about boot time or shutdown time? It's difficult to tell.

Answer (score 5):

Using one answer within [Ubuntu 15.04 network manager causing slow boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615006/ubuntu-15-04-network-manager-causing-slow-boot) worked for me:

```
systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

A bug report for 17.10 has already been filed and you may wish to subscribe to it:

- [NetworkManager-wait-online.service slows down boot](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1723809)