# Start graphical.target to be the first process to load at boot

Tags: systemd

Is it possible to start graphical.target to be the first process to load at boot and start other processes after that?

Comment: Why? I wouldn't mess with that crazy  hierarchy without a good reason.

Comment: I think a process like network manager can be started after that so we can access the desktop faster.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving graphical target higher up the list you can disable **some** of the services at the top of the list. Using one answer within [Ubuntu 15.04 network manager causing slow boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615006/ubuntu-15-04-network-manager-causing-slow-boot) worked for me:

```
systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```