# Ubuntu 18.04 is slow to boot, 53 seconds to reach multi-user target

Tags: boot, 18.04, hp, performance

Ubuntu noob here. How can I speed up boot of this system?

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

   graphical.target @53.066s
└─multi-user.target @53.066s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @37.351s +31ms
    └─snapd.service @30.360s +6.987s
      └─basic.target @29.615s
        └─sockets.target @29.615s
          └─snapd.socket @29.539s +75ms
            └─sysinit.target @29.538s
              └─cryptsetup.target @29.497s
                └─systemd-ask-password-wall.path @3.649s
                  └─-.mount @3.630s
                    └─system.slice @3.649s
                      └─-.slice @3.630s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should answer your question:

[Ubuntu 15.04 network manager causing slow boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615006/ubuntu-15-04-network-manager-causing-slow-boot)

In short you can just disable the service.

```
systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

Comment: I tried the command.., it reduce the time by a few seconds. Can i reduce it further... all the above mention things still take a lot of time

Comment: Please post the new output of the `systemd-analyze critical-chain` to see how it changed

Comment: updated ^, sorry noob here, don't know the edit code protocols yet...

Comment: Try disabling the winbind service if you don't need it [winbind service'(https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Managing_the_Samba_AD_DC_Service_Using_Systemd)  Specifically `systemctl disable smbd nmbd winbind`

Comment: It says permission denied.. can you guide me how to change this... I hope i dont have to re-install my OS from scratch for this

Comment: Prefix the command with sudo, example `sudo systemctl disable smbd nmdb winbind`

Comment: smbd.service does not exist

Comment: Then skip it.  Try just winbind.

Comment: done, updated the systemd-analyze output

Comment: You now have a pattern you can follow :)  Simply `sysemctl disable <service name>`  In thi slatest case just `systemctl disable snapd.service`

Comment: what is the effect of disabling each service?? does it affect my laptop's performance?

Comment: Here we're just booting up for speed as that is what you stated as most important.  The services the were disabled were all networking related.  You can google what each one does specifically as that's outside the scope of the question :)