# How to make Kubuntu boot faster?

Tags: kubuntu, boot-time

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @2min 9.351s
└─multi-user.target @2min 9.351s
  └─vmware-workstation-server.service @2min 884ms +8.466s
    └─vmware.service @1min 52.205s +8.677s
      └─network-online.target @1min 52.204s
        └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 41.125s +11.078s
          └─NetworkManager.service @1min 34.513s +6.529s
            └─dbus.service @1min 34.506s
              └─basic.target @1min 34.122s
                └─sockets.target @1min 34.122s
                  └─snapd.socket @1min 34.107s +14ms
                    └─sysinit.target @1min 34.049s
                      └─haveged.service @22.032s
                        └─apparmor.service @19.127s +2.894s
                          └─local-fs.target @19.066s
                            └─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @2min 43.718s
```

### inxi

```
$ inxi -Fxzr               
System:    Host: msra-Ideapad-Z570 Kernel: 4.18.0-13-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 8.2.0 
           Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.13.5 Distro: Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: HuronRiver Platform v: Ideapad Z570 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: LENOVO model: Emerald Lake v: FAB1 serial: <filter> UEFI: LENOVO v: 45CN38WW date: 10/21/2011 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 32.1 Wh condition: 32.4/48.8 Wh (66%) model: SANYO L08L6Y02 status: Unknown 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i5-2410M bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Sandy Bridge rev: 7 
           L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 18358 
           Speed: 1075 MHz min/max: 800/2900 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 844 2: 813 3: 877 4: 826 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GF108M [GeForce GT 520M] driver: nouveau v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.1 driver: intel resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Sandybridge Mobile v: 3.3 Mesa 18.2.2 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Family High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:1b.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GF108 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.1 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.18.0-13-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Broadcom and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter 
           driver: bcma-pci-bridge v: N/A bus ID: 03:00.0 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 2000 
           bus ID: 04:00.0 
           IF: enp4s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           Device-3: Ralink MT7601U Wireless Adapter type: USB driver: mt7601u bus ID: 1-1.3:4 
           IF: wlx3c33001bcb3c state: down mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-1: vmnet1 state: unknown speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-2: vmnet8 state: unknown speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-3: wlp3s0b1 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 712.96 GiB used: 436.40 GiB (61.2%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD7500BPVT-24HXZT1 size: 698.64 GiB temp: 44 C 
           ID-2: /dev/sdb type: USB vendor: SanDisk model: Ultra size: 14.32 GiB temp: 195 C 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 44.15 GiB used: 21.91 GiB (49.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda11 
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 3.72 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda13 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 69.0 C mobo: 52.0 C gpu: nouveau temp: 72 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Repos:     Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
           1: deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic main restricted
           2: deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates main restricted
           3: deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic universe
           4: deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates universe
           5: deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic multiverse
           6: deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates multiverse
           7: deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
           8: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security main restricted
           9: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security universe
           10: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security multiverse
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/indicator-brightness-ubuntu-ppa-cosmic.list 
           1: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/indicator-brightness/ppa/ubuntu cosmic main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-firefox-next-cosmic.list 
           1: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-next/ubuntu cosmic main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/noobslab-ubuntu-indicators-cosmic.list 
           1: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/indicators/ubuntu cosmic main
Info:      Processes: 263 Uptime: 1h 26m Memory: 3.77 GiB used: 2.04 GiB (54.2%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 
           Compilers: gcc: 8.2.0 Shell: bash v: 4.4.19 inxi: 3.0.24
```

Comment: **1**: Please install inxi using `sudo apt install inxi` and then post the output of `inxi -Fxzr` here by [editing your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1107328/edit). That'll give people an idea of your machine's specs and repos. **2**: If purchasing an SSD is out of the question, you need to ask yourself whether a slow boot time is really an issue. Do you have the need to reboot often? ... continued in next comment.

Comment: **3**: As your output shows, processes related to `vmware` seem to take the longest time. So maybe this has less to do with Kubuntu than with the virtualization software you installed. **4**: It's good practice to include the command as well, not just its output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 15.04 network manager causing slow boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615006/ubuntu-15-04-network-manager-causing-slow-boot)

Comment: How should i remove the duplicate?

Comment: The last entry in your critical chain indicates that you are waiting 43 seconds for a gvfs mount - a samba share from a windows machine perhaps?  There is some information relating to slow shares [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1043449/how-to-debug-slow-samba-share-by-nautilus) which indicate that cifs may be faster.

Answer (score 1):

One acronym - SSD - makes bootup a wonderful thing.

Comment: I an a new user! Please could you suggest exact steps?

Comment: Purchase a SSD. That will get your boot time at around 10 seconds. Better hardware will be the quickest boost to performance. Software adjustment is not going to get you any significant improvements.