# After 15.04 upgrade: Strange startup screen, long loading time?

Tags: startup, systemd

After upgrading my 14.10 to 15.04 (running gnome3 desktop), I have the following loading screen:
[image]
(photographed as I don't think there is an option to take a screenshot at this point, right?)
Shouldn't there some text be shown (where those ominous brownish-black bars are)? Or graphics? Where can I look to fix this?

Also, this is shown for quite a long time (at least one minute) - this used to go a lot faster before.
I heard of some startup system change (if I see it correctly it was changed from upstart to systemd, right?) Could that have to do with it? Where can I check what is causing the long delay? Tried searching but only came up with unanswered questions like this: [Ubuntu 15.04 SLOW BOOT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614140/ubuntu-15-04-slow-boot); I tried the answer mentioned here: [Ubuntu 15.04 network manager causing slow boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615006/ubuntu-15-04-network-manager-causing-slow-boot) but it only shows this:

```
      7.349s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      1.356s systemd-udev-settle.service
      1.025s plymouth-quit-wait.service
       395ms dev-disk-by\some-really-long-id.device
```

as first four and the times rapidly drop down to under 100ms (11th place only takes 74ms), so the sum does not add up to anywhere near the required startup time...